# MySQL: How can I check whether Users are listed or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exists

I was wondering how I can check whether users are already in the database or not.

In PHP I have an array with some UserIDs.
i.e. userIDs[0] = 1234; userIDs[1] = 2345;

Now I wanted to build a query to make just one sql call if possible to get following result:

```
############################
#    UserID    #   Exists  #
############################
#     1234     #     0     #
#     2345     #     1     #
############################
```

Is there a sql solution or do I have to check each ID with a seperate call?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use the `IN` clause... `SELECT... FROM... WHERE UserID IN (YourArray)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check existing `id`s against a list you can do

```
select userId, userId in (2345,5678) as `exists`
from your_table
order by userId
```

But to check if a list of `id`s is in the DB you can do

```
select tmp.userId, tab.userId is not null as `exists`
from
(
  select 1234 as userId
  union all
  select 2345
  union all
  select 3456
) tmp
left join db_table tab on tab.userId = tmp.userId
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy :) Thank you very much, I did not know the "in" statement!

Comment: this will give you all users 1000 records 1000 results , if userID 5678 not exists **it will not be in the resultset, not listed**. so the OP: **check whether users are already in the database** will not work.

Comment: I just realized it is the wrong way. This query you posted shows me if the id in the database is in my array. But I need the other way around. Is the ID from my array in my Database. I am not sure how to get that result.

Comment: Ahh, building up a table, that works for me! Thank you!

Comment: @SomehowLuke : and now how comes the array into play instead of hardcoded values ?

Comment: @moskito-x: Posted an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

x:

you build up your query in PHP which is string.

```
$idsFromFacebook = array(1234,2345,3456,4567);

//start query
$strQuery = "select tmp.userId, tab.userId is not null as `exists` from (";
$bfirstRun = true;

//Go through each element of the array and connect them with the query string
foreach( $idsFromFacebook as $userID )
{
     //There is no union all before the first element and after the last
     if ( !$bFirstRun )
          $strQuery .= " union all ";

     $strQuery .= "select ".$userID;

     if ( $bFirstRun )
     {
          //"as userId" is only needed the first time
          $strQuery .= " as userId";
          $bFirstRun = False
     }
}

//Finishing the query by joining the generated table with database
$strQuery .=  ") tmp left join db_table tab on tab.userId = tmp.userId;";

//Call Query
$result = $dbms->query($strQuery);
//...
```

That is pretty much it. Because the query is a string, you can build it up just like you want to have it :)

Comment: Not all users have time to test this query . Please show in your answer also. example Database name,fields. The created `$strQuery`, the result, the new created table, fields, content etc. So users can clearly see whats going on. Thx.

Comment: Sorry, I did not test it either, this is just an example how to build up a dynamic query. Once you have the build up query (it is still just a string, nothing else ;) ) you can use it just like a hardcoded...